# Namespaces and folder relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, resharper

Ok, I guess do namespaces have to be the same as the nested folders that their in?  I keep getting errors saying that the namespace should be xxx.yyy.zzz.

Example:

```
Folder1
    Folder2
        MyControl.cs
```

I have a namespace in it defined as:

```
namespace CustomControls
{

...

}
```

so the compiler is complaning that it must be namespace Folder1.Folder2

so is there a direct relation to file structure and namespaces?  Are you forced to have a tight relation to these?

Comment: Post the exact compiler error. I don't think its the compiler creating this error though (it doesn't care).

Comment: Also, say whether this is a web site or a web application project.

Comment: Is this a windows application, asp.net application, asp.net website?

Answer (score 6):

This is a warning Resharper usually reports. To exclude a folder from Resharper's folder tree - namespace comparison, go to the folder properties list in VS and set `Namespace Provider` to **false**.

Comment: What menus is this in?  I'm using VS 2008.  And yes I'm using ReSharper so that must be it

Comment: F4 opens the properties window if you don't have it open, then simply click on the folder in solution explorer and its properties will show up in the properties view.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether ASP.NET has some special rules (due to automatic compilation) but certainly in C# itself there are no *rules* saying you have to organise your folders to match your namespaces. It's a good idea from a maintainability point of view though.

Are you sure it's the compiler and not just another bit of ASP.NET (or even ReSharper?) complaining?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can have any namespace tree you want regardless of your folder structure. Visual Studio makes it easy on you to automatically create namespaces based on folder structure so you don't have to maintain namespace trees yourself. But does not force it in any ways shape or form.

The error you're getting doesn't have anything to do with your compiler.

You also don't have any tag saying what Dev IDE you're using.

Answer (score 0):

That has to be an error coming from ReSharper and not from Visual Studio's compiler. Right now I am actually having the *opposite* problem: I am trying to get VS2008 to automatically name my namespaces based on my nested folder structure like Folder1.Folder2.MyProjectName but it insists on naming it "flat" MyProjectName! So as Jon said, C# in itself is agnostic to namespace nomenclature.